How to test whether correlation of couples phenotypes is due to assortative mating or environment?
A few phenotypes are easier to pinpoint as assortative mating (height for example), But other phenotypes such as vitamin D, weight, etc could be a combination of shared environment and assortative mating. How could I disentangle those?
One idea was to compare against shared genetic variants associated to those traits. If couples also share these variants it is more likely to be AM rather than environment.
Do you have any other ideas? Unfortunately I don't have longitudinal data. And I only have data from mating pairs, not from offspring.
I am working with exome sequencing and genotype data. I have several phenotypes (anthropometric features, molecular traits, ICD10 codes).

Please give us a bit more detail. Should we assume you are working with human data? What kind of data do you actually have? Sequence? Variants? Expression? RNASeq? Phenotypical data? Family history? Clinical history?

I added some more details. I have exome+genotyping, phenotypical data, ICD10 codes.

I feel like you will have to account for population structure to say much about assortative mating. I'm not an expert in the field but I'd suggest reading up on what others have done, see e.g. https://journals.plos.org/plosgenetics/article?id=10.1371/journal.pgen.1006655

I'm working with europeans with white ancestry only, so population structure shouldn't be much of an issue.

This strikes me as a question that might be able to be answerable for model organisms like drosophila, but is hopeless in humans. What do  you mean by a "vitamin D" phenotype? Can humans even observe it? "If couples also share these variants it is more likely to be AM rather than environment." Not true! If the couples also all share the same or nearly the same environment, then the genetic variants are completely uninformative. For example, my wife and I both have blue eyes, but that has nothing to with the fact that we both get up at 7am, that's because we share an alarm clock.

Vitamin D levels in blood seems to be a highly correlated phenotype in my set of couples when compared to random. When I meant genetic variants I meant the variants relevant to the phenotype. So for example, SNPs relevant for height should be highly correlated among tall couples. But SNPs relevant for circadian rhythm(?) as you mention may not. As the environment could have a bigger impact than genetic predisposition.

"Vitamin D levels in blood seems to be a highly correlated phenotype" ok, but for assortive mating to be happening the couples would need have some sense of whether a potential mate matches the desired level of Vitamin D. How on earth would that be happening? Isn't measuring genetic variants associated with the correlated phenotype just re-measuring the correlation? On top of all that you have a multiple testing problem: if you start with a laundry list of possible phenotypes and then go looking for weird correlations you are almost certainly going to find them but mostly by chance.

My sense is that you could really only answer a question this with a multi-generational program with a model organism.

Yes I have no idea why they're so highly correlated. Perhaps it is another phenotype (more visible) related to that one that is driving the signal. I believe I have enough sample size for multiple testing not to be a problem. But I'm still not sure how to explain this. I'm a bioinformatician, so a model organism wouldn't be suitable for me. I guess given I don't have before mating and after mating data, I would be better off doing simulations. I just have to figure out the correct way to do it.
